# Как убрать определенный символ с начала новой линии строки?

Tags: python, строки

```
in C++ 
+#include <iostream>
+using namespace std;
+int main() {
+    cout << "Hello, World!";
+    return 0;
+}
```

Допустим у меня есть такой текст, как мне убрать плюсы в начале линий строки?
Код должен быть на пайтон, в интернете решения не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Python 3.10.0 (tags/v3.10.0:b494f59, Oct  4 2021, 19:00:18) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.8.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: text = """in C++
   ...: +#include <iostream>
   ...: +using namespace std;
   ...: +int main() {
   ...: +    cout << "Hello, World!";
   ...: +    return 0;
   ...: +}"""

In [2]: repr(text)
Out[2]: '\'in C++ \\n+#include <iostream>\\n+using namespace std;\\n+int main() {\\n+    cout << "Hello, World!";\\n+    return 0;\\n+}\''

In [3]: result = text.split("\n+")

In [4]:

In [4]: print(result)
['in C++ ', '#include <iostream>', 'using namespace std;', 'int main() {', '    cout << "Hello, World!";', '    return 0;', '}']

In [5]: new_text = "".join(string + "\n" for string in result)

In [6]: print(new_text)
in C++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Hello, World!";
    return 0;
}


In [7]:
```

Comment: Можно ещё и плюсик добавить ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Я советую метод `setf` из заголовка `iomanip`. Для удаления символа пробела с начала новой строки подойдёт:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    cout << setw(15) << setfill(' ') << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

в коде `setw(int)` устанавливает ширину вывода, а `setfill(char)` устанавливает символ заполнения для вывода, который может быть использован для заполнения до нужной ширины.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, но мне нужно было решение на python. В любом случае я иногда пишу на C++.